# Objective C Char for loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

Whats wrong with this for loop in Objective C?
I get an "Expected Expression" error

```
for (char c = ‘A’; c <= ‘Z’; c++)
{
   //Do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  An easy mistake now I know but a valid question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you by any chance copy and paste it? The code reads fine, but is wrong because you've used `‘A’` rather than `'A'`. Change the quotes to proper single quotes.

Comment: You caught me, it was a copy and paste! Good spot.  I have to wait ten mins to accept your answer

Answer (score 7):

You're using the wrong characters to brace each `char`, possibly a result of the type of keyboard you're using?  You need the single apostrophe character to denote a `char`.  Try this:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    //Do stuff 
}
```